# difference: return promise and return promise.then

Tags: javascript, promise

I have such method in my factory

```
getTogether() {
        let promise = this._$q.all([this._$http.get('/groups'), this._$http.get('/tasks')]);
        return promise
            .then((data) => {
                //local variable for reduce server<->client
                this._localList = data;
                return this._localList;
            });
    };
```

and I call this method in my controller.

```
this._boardFactory.getTogether().then((list) => {
            console.log(list)
        });
```

all works perfectly, however I don't understand one thing.

**what's the difference between return `promise` and return `promise.then`?**

thanks for your attantion

Comment: promise.then returns another promise, which will resolve to the value you returned in the `.then` callback

Comment: In your case, no difference, other than the fact that they're two different promises that are resolved with the same value.

Comment: Agree with Kevin. You will notice that you are getting the same result in console log with or without `.then`

Comment: @Pranay Rana thx for full explanation, i think that i understand it  now

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I say `Promise` is object and `then()` is method on Promise object which reruns another Promise.

`Promise.prototype.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)`- Appends fulfillment and rejection handlers to the promise, and returns a new promise resolving to the return value of the called handler, or to its original settled value if the promise was not handled (i.e. if the relevant handler onFulfilled or onRejected is not a function).
Below image explains thing :

[image]

Read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

this is how it gose

```
-Promise - let this is ajax call,
  - then() - now this allows you to work on the output you received from first promise
     - then() - now if you want to work on the output of second promise which return by then(first) 
       - then - another promise allows to wok on ouput of third
```

so it kind of chaining ...go on ..till you complete it

Answer (score 0):

If you only do `return promise` in your code, you will return the resolution of the `promise` object. However, if you do `return promise.then` you will return the resolution of the promise from the `then` clause.

`then` returns a promise, so `promise.then` will execute `promise` then execute the `then` clause returning that promise.

More info on `then` here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Only answer that mentions the `then()` returns a new promise